# Return items from array with index 1 to 5 Javascript

Tags: javascript

How can i console.log items from index 1 to 5 in current array? Using Loop

```js
let cars = ["AUDI","BMW","LEXUS","VOLKSWAGEN","FERRARY","PORSCHE"]

const mappedCars=cars.map((item, i) => {
    console.log("The current index is: " + i);
    console.log("The current element is: " + item);
    console.log("\n");
    return item; //equivalent to list[index]
});

console.log(mappedCars);
```

Comment: from index 1 to 5 should be ```cars.slice(1,6)```

Comment: the tasks asks me to do it in loop

Comment: If you must use a loop, you'll need to create an empty array, loop over the indexes you want and push the entries in to the new array

Comment: I tried to do it but my brain is over exhausted,sorry for bothering you more but can you give me simple example?

Comment: What happens if the array is shorter than 5? What happens if it's shorter than 1? What should the result be for these edge-cases?

Comment: The task is just to loop over an existing array and console.log item from index 1 to 5 , that cases does not exist in task

Comment: Also array is given in task already,It s not created manually

Comment: Your question says _"How can i **return** items..."_ which is quite different to just `console.log()`. You should always be thinking of boundary conditions for your code. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62629856/edit) to describe **exactly** what you're trying to do and what should happen in unfavourable conditions

Comment: Sorry, i fixed it

Comment: `for(var i=1; i<=Math.min(5, cars.length-1); i++) console.log("Index="+i+" Value="+cars[i]);`  If there are less than two cars, no output.  if there are less than 6 cars, output will be less than 5 cars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this in a **loop** for indexes 1 to 5 (inclusive):

```js
let cars = ["AUDI","BMW","LEXUS","VOLKSWAGEN","FERRARY","PORSCHE"]

const filteredCars = [];
for (let i=1; i<=5; i++) {
        filteredCars.push(cars[i]);
}

console.log(filteredCars);
```

Without loop you may also use `filter()` or `slice()`. See example with `filter()`:

```js
let cars = ["AUDI","BMW","LEXUS","VOLKSWAGEN","FERRARY","PORSCHE"]

const filteredCars=cars.filter((item, i) => i>=1 && i<=5);

console.log(filteredCars);
```

Comment: Thank you  very much

Comment: Why are you performing unnecessary iterations. `for (let i = 1; i <=5; i++)` seems more appropriate

Comment: Edited  - Thanks

Answer (score 3):

With a for loop:

```js
let cars = ["AUDI","BMW","LEXUS","VOLKSWAGEN","FERRARY","PORSCHE"]

for(i = 1; i<cars.length; i++){
    console.log("The current index is: " + i);
    console.log("The current element is: " + cars[i]);
    console.log("\n");
};
```

Answer (score 3):

With `for loop` you can define the initial condition as well as loop terminating condition.

```
for ([initialExpression]; [condition]; [incrementExpression])
 statement
```

```
let cars = ["AUDI","BMW","LEXUS","VOLKSWAGEN","FERRARY","PORSCHE"]

const updated = [];
for (let i=1; i<=5; i++) {
        updated.push(cars[i]);
}

console.log(updated);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `forEach` :

```js
let cars = ["AUDI","BMW","LEXUS","VOLKSWAGEN","FERRARY","PORSCHE"];

function repea (element, index) {
  console.log(`The current index is: ${index}`);
  console.log(`The current element is: ${element}`);
}


cars.forEach(repea);
```